# How to delete line of file if a part of a name is typed into input?

Tags: python

I have a phonebook that is working decently, and for my delete entry function I am not sure how to make it so you are able to type in just the first name of the person you want to be deleted, and it will delete their whole contact.

Here is the code:

```
def deleteEntry():
    file = open("phone.txt")
    phonebook = readFile("phone.txt")
    while True:
        try:
            delete = input("Which entry would you like to delete?(enter name)")
            print()
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, that didn't make sense. Try again.")
            print()
            continue
        else:
            break
            print()
    with open("phone.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("phone.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != delete:
                f.write(line)
```

This works when I type the entire name and entire number separated by a comma (that is how the text is formatted in the txt file.)
Is there any way to make this function recognize if a first name is inputted?

Comment: Please work through a tutorial on string processing.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials.

Comment: Appreciate it. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    file = open("phone.txt")
    phonebook = readFile("phone.txt")
    while True:
        try:
            delete = input("Which entry would you like to delete?(enter name)")
            print()
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, that didn't make sense. Try again.")
            print()
            continue
        else:
            break
            print()
    with open("phone.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("phone.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if delete not in line.strip("\n"):
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: smart. I will try it

Comment: well.. this deleted all of the lines in the file

Comment: Well I missed the _not_ operator . Try now

Comment: dang, i should have saw that too! I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` keyword

Such as in

```
If 'search' in 'research':
```

This will do a contains search on the second string

Edit::

Modify your for loop to feature the code like the following

```
If delete in line:
```

Comment: That is what I figured. But Where would if I put the ``` in ``` before delete then it would say ``` if line.strip("\n") in delete: ```

Comment: I have modified my answer